# Google App Engine "Error: Server Error" for sample project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine and just deployed a sample project ["flask"](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.66976942.1010838692.1445570346) to my GAE. But it shows

> "Error: Server Error
>   The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds."

I have read a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow, but I don't find any who has this problem even for the sample project provided by GAE itself.

Comment: You need to check the logs in the development console to see what the error description is.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and found the answer in the sample project README file. The problem was that flask isn't included in the sample project, so I was getting an flask import error. You just have to cd to your project directory (appengine-flask-skeleton-master) and run the following...

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

If you are on linux you will probably need to include sudo before the command.

You should now see flask in the lib folder in the sample project directory. If you update your project again, the import error should be resolved.

You can test your app locally by running:

`dev_appserver.py .`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi I just did as you said and I want to update the project to test. However, when I use command "appcfg.py -A my-first-gae-project-1119 update app.yaml ", everything after "appcfg.py" seems to be neglected. It only shows the menu of "appcfg.py", even if I type something arbitrary like "appcfg.py sagioahfh...". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I'm not sure what the problem could be.  Were you able to test the app locally by running: 'dev_appserver.py . ' ?   I've edited my answer to include that command.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well the problem is confirmed to be a windows bug...However we have figured out other ways to do the same.

Comment: The browser error isn't very useful as it's just a generic error message, so as GAEfan stated above you absolutely need to check your logs to find out what the exact error is in the stack trace. For Cyrus it meant flask was missing, for you it could be something else. If your app tried to divide by zero you would still get this exact same error in the browser.